# Linux: configure font to be treated as monospace

Tags: linux, fonts, fontconfig

I'm trying to use the OCR-A font on Ubuntu. But it's not configured properly to be recgnized as monospace font.

I understand that I need to have a local fonts.conf file or somethign like that. But not sure how to prepare it.

Any example?

Comment: Is that even possible?

Comment: In this case it's a misconfiguration. So it's possible.

Comment: I don't understand that "local fonts.conf" part.  How did you install the font?

Comment: @tink: installed through ttf-ocr-a package. There could be a $HOME/.font/fonts.conf, right?

Comment: aaah. I think I get it. try `locate fonts.conf` -> /etc/fonts/fonts.conf